# Add Rewrite Rule to point to a file on the server

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I'm trying to add a rewrite rule that will point to a file inside a plugin. This can be added in the plugin, theme or .htaccess file.

My current code from inside the theme's function.php looks like:

```
// Add Custom Rewrite Rules
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  flush_rewrite_rules();
  add_rewrite_rule('^leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/index.php?leaf=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

**Note:** I'm trying to do this on a Multisite network for a path based subdomain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(Revised answer)*

1. *Don't call `flush_rewrite_rules()` on `init`.* Instead, if you want to do it programmatically, call the function from your plugin or theme activation function. If you're not doing it programmatically, you could simply visit the Permalink Settings page (Settings → Permalinks on the WordPress back-end).
2. *WordPress does support adding a rewrite rule that doesn't correspond to `index.php`*, i.e. the second parameter passed to `add_rewrite_rule()` **does *not* necessarily need to** start with `index.php` — and when it doesn't, WordPress will (attempt to automatically) write the rewrite rule to the `.htaccess` file.

   However, your code should look like so, where the *first parameter* should not start with a caret (`^`), and the *second parameter* should use `$1` instead of `$matches[1]` (`$matches[1]` is only for rewrite rule which corresponds to the WordPress's `index.php`):

   ```php
   add_rewrite_rule('leaf/([0-9]+)/?', 'wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/index.php?leaf=$1', 'top');
   ```

   And if your `.htaccess` file is [writable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions), then after the rewrite rules are *flushed*, you should see something like this in the file:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteRule ^leaf/([0-9]+)/? /wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/index.php?leaf=$1 [QSA,L]
   ```

   The "leaf" value would be available in the (superglobal) `$_GET` and within your `index.php` file, you could do:

   ```
   <p><?php echo $_GET['leaf']; ?></p>
   ```
3. Instead of using `add_rewrite_rule()`, you could also use the `parse_request` action hook to handle the URL/request and then load the custom plugin file. Working example:

   ```php
   <?php
   add_action( 'parse_request', function( $wp ){
       if ( preg_match( '#^leaf/([0-9]+)/?#', $wp->request, $matches ) ) {
           $leaf = $matches[1];

           // Load your file - make sure the path is correct.
           include_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'index.php';

           exit; // and exit
       }
   } );
   ```

   So as you can see, the "leaf" value is saved to the `$leaf` variable. So within your `index.php` file, you could do:

   ```
   <p><?php echo $leaf; ?></p>
   ```

   *With the `parse_request` hook, you don't need to worry about your `.htaccess` file not being writable;* however, the `$_GET['leaf']` wouldn't be available, which explains why we use the `$leaf` variable. :)

   But yes, although I don't recommend it, you could do `$_GET['leaf'] = $matches[1];` and the `$_GET['leaf']` would be available in your script. ;)

Answer (score 2):

@Sally CJ,

Thank you very much for your reply. You gave me a great direction. Don't have enough reputation yet, but I would definitely Upvote your answer.

My current code (inside the child theme) looks like this:

```
<?php

    add_action( 'parse_request', function( $wp ){
      // The regex can be changed depending on your needs
      if ( preg_match( '#^leaf/(.*)/?#', $wp->request, $matches ) ) {
        // Get the Leaf Number
        $leaf = $matches[1]; 

        // Define it for my-plugin's index.php
        $_GET['leaf'] = urldecode($leaf);

        // Load your file - make sure the path is correct.
        include_once WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/plugins/my-plugin/index.php';
        exit; // and exit
      }
    });
```

You can test your regex here: https://www.regextester.com/96691

Comment: Hey Theo. I'm glad my answer helped you and I've revised it - I hope it is more helpful now. :) And actually, I +1 your answer, so you could upvote my answer.. or accept it. ;) I mean, you should accept your answer or mine so that people know the question has an *accepted solution*. =) Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much Sally. You're a real lady! I've accepted your answer of course.

Answer (score 0):

As @SallyCJ mentioned, your .htaccess file must be writable. For this, use the default file permissions `644`.

But in my case, it wasn't enough. Using `flush_rewrite_rules` didn't help too.

WP wrote the rule into the `.htaccess` file only after I had done

```
WP Admin -> Settings -> Permalinks -> Save
```